# Kendo UI Multi Select List Item Per Row

Tags: html, asp.net, razor, kendo-ui

Anyone know how to use the Kendo UI Multiselect so it displays the selected items in a list vertically instead of in-line.

By default it displays it like this:

```
| [Item 1] [Item 2] [Item 3] |
```

But I want to display it like this:

```
| [Item 1] |
| [Item 2] |
| [Item 3] |
```

Does anyone know how I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

all you need to do is to change the width of your multiselect

```
 .HtmlAttributes(new { @style="width: 100px;"})
```

Comment: What will happen if the text is longer then 100px?

Comment: Tried this, not going to work. Because if the item string length is too long, it drops down to a new line. when you have 2 string which is both say 50 px long, then they still stack next to each other

Comment: Its an alright solution if all the strings are about the same num of characters plus or minus 25%. Still looking for a better solution tho.

Answer (score 4):

You can target the items inside the control with this style, so they all become full-width:

```
<style>
    div.k-multiselect-wrap .k-button {
        width: 100%;
   } 
</style>
```

Comment: Worked for me, when the solution on the Telerik website failed.