# Angular2 + Kendo MultiSelect list each item per row

Tags: html, css, angular, kendo-ui, kendo-multiselect

I have an Angular2 Kendo MultiSelect componenet in my app. My business requirement is to list each selection per row instead of stacking them next to each other. How do I achieve this?

I did a search and found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28161534/kendo-ui-multi-select-list-item-per-row). Implemented the proposed style by setting width to 100px but this would not work in my scenario because the multiselect selections are going to be longer than 100px.

One way that I found this to work with my multiselect is by setting width to 500px for the multiselect control. In that case it is dropping each item in its own row but the size of the multiselect is not taking the full width of the page.

**How can i achieve each item per row with Kendo Multiselect length set to full width ?**

Answer (score 0):

The Multiselect consists of an UL LI list where the list takes the full width. So if you set this style

```
.k-multiselect-wrap ul { width: 1%;}
```

the list tries to take just 1% and thei items line wrap. It's an ugly hack but could do it ;-). It might have side effects on different browsers.

I have modified the Progress Plunker example: http://embed.plnkr.co/sOBzjul7e2OdI8Ig2VLE/

Comment: Thanks for your response Ludwig. But for some reason when I implement this css my items in multiselect are wrapping because their length is greater than 1%.